# Making app to count time since first time used

Tags: java, android, time, elapsedtime

How to make an app to count the time since the first time opened? I have no idea which class to use. Is it possible to achieve this with a stopwatch or something similar? Can someone pls share some code? I don't know what to search on the internet just have an idea of what I want to build. Or just tell me an idea with what I can achieve this and how?

```
 statisticLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          if (plusiliminus==0){
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(),R.string.toaststatistic,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } else {
              Fragment fragmentstatistic=new Statistic();
              FragmentTransaction transaction=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
              transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout,fragmentstatistic).commit();
          }
      }
  });
```

Comment: Do you want to keep track of the time for each launch of the application or the time when it was installed and opened the first time only?

Comment: i need to get time when app is used first time,then reset in on the button,then show it in textview,but it must run and count even when app is closed

Comment: Did you search for terms like stopwatch or elapsed time? I think you want the `Duration` class. You may also search for how to format a `Duration` into hours, minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You have basically to do two things.

Get the current time when you start the app, or press a button using something like

```
Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
```

This is a good beginning, you get the time, then you have to parse this time in a format you want to show to the user then you manage a stop and reset button as showed for instance in this [tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-stop-watch-android-application-tutorial/)

So you build a TextView and you show in real time the seconds, parsed in the way you need

```
import android.os.Handler;  
import android.os.SystemClock;  
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.widget.Button;  
import android.widget.TextView;  

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  

    TextView timer ;  
    Button start, pause, reset;  
    long MillisecondTime, StartTime, TimeBuff, UpdateTime = 0L ;  
    Handler handler;  
    int Seconds, Minutes, MilliSeconds ;  

    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

        timer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);  
        start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btStart);  
        pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btPause);  
        reset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btReset);  

        handler = new Handler() ;  

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View view) {  

                StartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();  
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);  

                reset.setEnabled(false);  

            }  
        });  

        pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View view) {  

                TimeBuff += MillisecondTime;  

                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);  

                reset.setEnabled(true);  

            }  
        });  

        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View view) {  

                MillisecondTime = 0L ;  
                StartTime = 0L ;  
                TimeBuff = 0L ;  
                UpdateTime = 0L ;  
                Seconds = 0 ;  
                Minutes = 0 ;  
                MilliSeconds = 0 ;  

                timer.setText("00:00:00");  

            }  
        });  

    }  

    public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {  

        public void run() {  

            MillisecondTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - StartTime;  

            UpdateTime = TimeBuff + MillisecondTime;  

            Seconds = (int) (UpdateTime / 1000);  

            Minutes = Seconds / 60;  

            Seconds = Seconds % 60;  

            MilliSeconds = (int) (UpdateTime % 1000);  

            timer.setText("" + Minutes + ":"  
                    + String.format("%02d", Seconds) + ":"  
                    + String.format("%03d", MilliSeconds));  

            handler.postDelayed(this, 0);  
        }  

    };  

}
```

and the view of `activity_main.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"  
        tools:context="in.amitsin6h.stopwatch.MainActivity">  



            <RelativeLayout  
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"  
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"  
                android:paddingBottom="90dp">  


               <TextView  
                   android:text="00:00:00"  
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                   android:id="@+id/tvTimer"  
                   android:textSize="50dp"  
                   android:textStyle="bold"  
                   android:textColor="#ffffff"  
                   android:layout_marginTop="120dp"  
                   android:paddingBottom="50dp"  
                   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />  

               <Button  
                   android:text="Start"  
                   android:background="#ffffff"  
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                   android:layout_below="@+id/tvTimer"  
                   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
                   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"  
                   android:layout_marginTop="41dp"  
                   android:id="@+id/btStart" />  

               <Button  
                   android:text="Pause"  
                   android:background="#ffffff"  
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                   android:id="@+id/btPause"  
                   android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btStart"  
                   android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btStart"  
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />  

               <Button  
                   android:text="Reset"  
                   android:background="#ffffff"  
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                   android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btPause"  
                   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
                   android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"  
                   android:id="@+id/btReset" />  

            </RelativeLayout>  


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: but i need to show this time in textview hours,minutes,seconds

Comment: yeah this is shown in the tutorial I gave you, you create a TextView and then you bind it to the view, deciding how should be shown, you understand that you asked for a tutorial, not to write an app:) stack overflow is for a single question if you get a block, not to write an app from scratch

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could understand, you need persistent storage for the time when it was first used. I think `SharedPreferences` is a good way of storing this in your case.

In the `onCreate` function of your launcher activity, you might get the `System.currentTimeInMillis()` and store it in the `SharedPreferences` [as stated here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences).

Then when you need to reset the time, you just have to clear the value in the `SharedPreferences` and can set a new value again.

I hope this gives you an idea of your implementation.